# Open Google Chrome at launch on multi monitor system (LINUX)

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-monitors, xorg, ubuntu-11.10, amd-catalyst

I have an AMD HD6950 video card with the latest catalyst drivers installed on a 64bit Ubuntu 11.10 linux box. There are currently two 1920 x 1080 HDTVs connected but there will be four in the future, this card can handle up to six at once.  My browser of choice is Google Chrome.

I need to have multiple browser windows open up in kiosk mode; one on each monitor after launch. Each browser window will also be a different web page address which are fetched from an Intranet.

What would be the correct setup in catalyst to accommodate this and how would I make Chrome open in each of the monitors as previously defined? I will try anything including working with xll, sessions or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

The Compiz config settings manager has lots of options för window placement and such. 
Install it if you havn't already `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager.`

Then go to:
*ccsm -> Window Management -> Place (plugin) -> Fixed window placement -> Windows with fixed viewport*

Answer (score -1):

nVidia's answer to this is the nView Desktop Manager - it looks something like this:

[image: nView Desktop Manager]

I'd take a look through Catalyst and see if ATi offers any similar options. If you can't find anything, it looks as though this may do the job: [devilspie](http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie)