# 4 browsers instances autoconfigured to 4 monitors on logon Debian

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-monitors

This might be wishful thinking... but stranger things have been found on the beach.

I have a Debian system with KDE desktop and a NVidia GeForce GTX750 running 4 monitors.

I want a new browser window to open in each monitor with a specific address in each instance, automatically on login.

Suggestions?

Comment: See [Tool to arrange browser windows on multiple monitors, interact with web page - all on startup?](http://superuser.com/questions/710219/tool-to-arrange-browser-windows-on-multiple-monitors-interact-with-web-page-a) Also [related](http://superuser.com/questions/391371/open-google-chrome-at-launch-on-multi-monitor-system-linux).

Answer (score 0):

kwin can easily create Window rules to achieve the positioning outcome without 3rd party software... in combination with a simple startup script.

Sleep always helps with these things :)